# Edit comments next to each file/directory

Tags: git, github

How can I edit those comments next to each file or directory? I can't find anything relevant when searching online.

[image: 1]

Comment: This comments are the commits comments.

Comment: @joseripla How do I actually add those comments ? [this](http://i.gyazo.com/e0d49e11e2a9a99a2cd2df012c36507b.png) is how my screen looks like

Comment: When you commit changes with git. > git commit -am "This is a comment"

Comment: @joseripla How does this specify the exact folder or file of which the comment will be added next to

Comment: with > git status , you can see the changes.

Comment: Here's the git commit documentation -> https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html

Comment: i write the answer to help you and others ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comments are the commits comments.

You can edit the comments that has not been pushed online (not your case) with :

```
git commit --amend
```

If you have pushed your commits you will have to force push a commit with an amended message:

```
git push --force example-branch
```

Docs:

- Here's a [link](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/) with a good github article explaining this.
- [Git-commit](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) oficial docs.

Comment: Force pushing is something that should generally be avoided, especially on shared codebases. Please don't advise users to force push without any kind of warning!

Comment: Totally agree, but its the behaviour that Shiro expect.